# How to add highlight to php tags in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

In netbeans these tags by default appear as plain text black with no highlight:

```
<?php 
?>
```

I'd like to highlight them to a light color, but don't see them as an option in
tools > options >fonts and colors> highlighting, and not in the php or misc options either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I found the option here:

Under Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Syntax

Language: php

Php open/close tag